# Cannot read property of "then" of undefined APOLLO GRAPHQL

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I'm having a trouble and i'm stuck. I used to replicate this on my other codes but this method doesn't work on apollo. Here is my method using the apollo on my vue.js.

```
handleLikePost() {
    const variables = {
        postId: this.postId,
        username: this.user.username
    };
    this.$apollo.mutate({
        mutation: LIKE_POST,
        variables,
        update: (cache, { data: { likePost } }) => {
            const data = cache.readQuery({
                query: GET_POST,
                variables: { postId: this.postId }
            });
            data.getPost.likes += 1;
            cache
                .writeQuery({
                query: GET_POST,
                variables: { postId: this.postId },
                data
            })
                .then(({ data }) => {
                // const updatedUser = {
                    //   ...this.user,
                    //   favorites: data.likePost.favorites
                    // };
                //this.$store.commit("setUser", updatedUser);
                console.log(this.user);
                console.log(data.likePost);
            })
                .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not returning something from;

`cache.writeQuery()`

That's why `.then({data})` is not getting something from `writeQuery()`